# Android Jetpack Compose - Animate canvas path inside LazyRow

Tags: android, animation, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

i'm new to android compose, i'm trying to animate a canvas path inside items in a LazyRow. 
 When application is running, if i scroll back and forth, before animations ends, some elements do not draw correctly. Cannot figure out if is a state problem or what else. 
Is it also possible to animate only one time per element, so when scrolling the same element animation will not repeat?
Below the code used for the test. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
@Composable
private fun drawPointsAnimation() {
    LazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    ) {
        items(15) { _ ->
            val points = getPoints(
                path = getPathBox(
                    Size(LocalDensity.current.run { 50.dp.toPx() },
                        LocalDensity.current.run { 50.dp.toPx() })
                )
            )
            val pointsCopy = mutableListOf<Offset>()
            var targetIndexValue by remember {
                mutableStateOf(0)
            }

            val currentIndex by animateIntAsState(
                targetValue = targetIndexValue,
                animationSpec = tween(4000, easing = LinearEasing)
            )
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                targetIndexValue = points.size - 1
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .width(
                        50.dp
                    )
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    pointsCopy.add(points[currentIndex])
                    drawPoints(
                        points = pointsCopy,
                        strokeWidth = 3f,
                        pointMode = PointMode.Lines,
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private fun getPoints(path: Path): MutableList<Offset> {
    val pm = android.graphics.PathMeasure(path.asAndroidPath(), false)
    val pointsList = mutableListOf<Offset>()
    var i = 0.0f
    while (i < 1) {
        val aCoordinates = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f)
        pm.getPosTan(pm.length * i, aCoordinates, null)
        pointsList.add(Offset(x = aCoordinates[0], y = aCoordinates[1]))
        i += 0.01f
    }
    return pointsList
}

private fun getPathBox(size: Size): Path {
    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0f)
    path.lineTo(0f, size.height)

    return path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare all of the variable to do the animation inside the `item()` block. I guess everytime the list need to render an item at some index it will re-declare you variable value, so that's why the animation is restarted. Maybe try to declare variable outside of the `item()` block? Like store `animateIntAsState()` inside a list and access that value for each of the item index independently?